# can't build: undefined reference to 'Battery::Battery()'...relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Battery::Battery()'

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, undefined, truncated

I am having an issue building and running unit tests in netbeans. The error is in the title above as well as the dump below.[enter image description here][1]

```
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Device.o: In function `Device::Device()':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Rover/Device.cpp:11:
undefined reference to 'Battery::Battery()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Rover/Device.cpp:11:(.text+0x26): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Battery::Battery()'
```

I receive three of the same errors for different lines in my code:

```
#include "Device.h"

Battery _battery; //error here
Device::Device() //error here
{
}

Device::Device(const Device& orig) { //error here
}

Device::~Device() {
}

void Device::operate() 
{

}

Battery Device::getBattery()
{
    return _battery;
}
```

Device header file ->

```
#include "Battery.h"

#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H



class Device {
public:
    Device();
    Device(const Device& orig);
    virtual ~Device();

    virtual void operate();
    Battery getBattery();
  //bool connectBattery();
  //bool disconnectBattery();

private:
    Battery _battery;

};

#endif  /* DEVICE_H */
```

Battery.cpp

```
    #include "Battery.h"
    int _power;
    Battery::Battery(int power) 
    {
        _power=power;
    }

    Battery::Battery(const Battery& orig) 
    {
    }

    Battery::~Battery() 
    {
    }

    bool Battery::Charge(int pUnit)
    {
        _power += pUnit;
        return true;
    }

    bool Battery::Discharge(int pUnit)
    {
        _power -= pUnit;
        return true;
    }
```

Battery.h

```
#ifndef BATTERY_H
#define BATTERY_H

class Battery {
public:
    Battery();
    Battery(int power);
    Battery(const Battery& orig);
    virtual ~Battery();

    bool Charge(int pUnit);
    bool Discharge(int pUnit);
private:
    int _power;
};

#endif  /* BATTERY_H */
```

Any help would be great, I have been tossing with this issue for a while now..
edit: I am also testing project with Alt-F6 + cppunit tests

Comment: Did you compile and link against `Battery.cpp`? (Assuming "Batter.cpp" in your question is a typo).

Comment: yes that is a typo my bad
when you say link against Battery.cpp what do you mean, I am just running alt-f6 for tests without any linkers

Comment: I solved my own problem ->
I changed Battery _battery to Battery* _battery; and corresponding getBattery()-> instead of getBattery().charge() and also the function Battery* getBattery()
{}